# Area between $ y=\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ and $y=x^2$, functional equations

Tags: calculus, transcendental-equations

Find the Area between $ y=\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ and $y=x^2$

So I know how to solve this specific case, but one thing I'm not sure of let's say we have:

$y=x^2$ and $\:y=\sin \:\left(ax\right)\:$

How do I find where they intercept?
 $$\:x^2=\sin \:\left(ax\right)\:$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of equation ($x^2=\sin(ax)$) is usually only solvable using numerical methods. However, in this case, you can compute two fixed points easily ($x=0$ and $x=1$). Then comparing the derivatives of the two functions can help you proving that these two points are the only intersections between the two graphs.